# pug - Incorrect nesting after compilation - include vs extend

Tags: html, node.js, express, pug

**Edit:** Modified the Title based on the correct answer, to help with googling

---

In the below code, my `h2` tag in the `404.pug` page keeps becoming a child of the `h1` tag after I include my `header.pug` in the `404.pug` page. Here's the code I'm working with:

**Header.pug**

```
doctype
html
  head
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    title Express Guestbook
    link(href="to/bootstrap.min.css", rel="stylesheet")

  body.container
    h1 Express Guestbook
      a.btn.btn-primary.pull-right(href="/new-entry") Write in Guestbook

    //- putting this div here so that whatever code 'include'-s this 
    //- header, will be a child of this div
    div
```

**404.pug**

```
include header.pug

  //- This part becomes child of <a> tag, instead of <div>
  h2 404! Page not found

include footer.pug
```

Can someone explain

1. Why is this happening? And,
2. Possibly show a way to keep the `h2` tag as a sibling of the `h1` and not become a child of the `a` tag?

Now a possible way to fix the issue would be to have a nested div (one div inside another) instead of just one single div, like this:

```
body.container
  h1 Express Guestbook
    a.btn.btn-primary.pull-right(href="/new-entry") Write in Guestbook

  //- ugly hack
  div: div
```

But this doesn't feel good..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to do an `extends header.pug` instead of `include header.pug`. `include` arbitrarily includes all the code from the target file without worrying about what else is on the page. That's not what you want here. An `extends header.pug` allows the `header.pug` file to render itself, plus additional code that you would define using a `block`. So you'd have to change your code to look like this:

**header.pug**

```
doctype
html
    head
        meta(charset='utf-8')
        title Express Guestbook
        link(href="to/bootstrap.min.css", rel="stylesheet")

    body.container
        h1 Express Guestbook
            a.btn.btn-primary.pull-right(href="/new-entry") Write in Guestbook

        //- putting this div here so that whatever code 'include'-s this 
        //- header, will be a child of this div
        div
            block content
```

The `block content` line will be replaced with whatever you choose to define `block content` to be in another Pug file. This makes more sense in the next file.

**404.pug**

```
extends header.jade

//- Everything that is a child of "block content" replaces the "block content"
//- from our "header.pug" file
block content
    h2 404! Page not found
```

The resulting HTML output is thus...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Express Guestbook</title>
    <link href="to/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body class="container">
    <h1>Express Guestbook<a href="/new-entry" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Write in Guestbook</a></h1>
    <div>
      <h2>404! Page not found</h2>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is great! I did read about the concepts in the docs, but it makes much more sense now!

Comment: Glad I could help! Feel free to read more about how `extend` works [here](https://pugjs.org/language/inheritance.html)